# C# search for words stored in clipboard and output searched words to the clipboard

Tags: c#, list, clipboard, contains

I am new to C# and need help formatting this code I am trying read from the clipboard for specific words then output it back to the clipboard.  There will need to be an endless number or words for me to add in the string list search.

```
Text = Clipboard.GetText();

string Text = "Text to analyze for words, chair, table";

List<string> words = new List<string> { "chair", "table", "desk" };

var result = words.Where(i => Text.Contains(i)).ToList();

TextOut = Clipboard.SetText();

\\outputs “chair, table” to the clipboard
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you have is that `result` is a list of words, but you can't put a list on the clipboard.  You have to turn it into a string.

You can do this using the Join method (string.Join), and specifying what you want to put in between the words, which is a comma and a space:

```
        //string Text = Clipboard.GetText();
        string Text = "Text to analyze for words, chair, table";

        List<string> words = new List<string> { "chair", "table", "desk" };

        // No need for ToList - the enumerable will work with Join
        IEnumerable<string> foundWords = words.Where(i => Text.Contains(i)); 
        string result = string.Join(", ", foundWords);
        Clipboard.SetText(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is nearly fine.

I think you need to split words in your clipboard with spaces or commas but you need to find something to do this.

and then :

```cs
var Text = Clipboard.GetText();

//imagine you have words, chair, table
//you split to have an array containing 
var arrayString = Text.Split(',')

List<string> wordsToSearch = new List<string> { "chair", "table", "desk" };

//you check your list
var result = wordswordsToSearch.Where(i => arrayString.Contains(i)).ToList();

//and set clipboard with matching content
var TextOut = Clipboard.SetText(result);

\\outputs “chair, table” to the clipboard
```

I don't know if my code works but this is the idea from what i understood from your need.

Comment: I think you should have tested if it works, Alexandre Castro! result is a list, but you can't use SetText with a list, so your code doesn't compile.

Comment: If the list is already separated by commas on the input do I still need to split the text?  var result = wordswordsToSearch.Where  should "words" be in there twice?